# IIS Redirect rule for uncertain sub-directory

Tags: redirect, iis

I  need to write a rule to achieve these:

```
<rule name="Redirect Category No Parent" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^content/category/([a-zA-Z\d-_\s]+)(/[a-zA-Z\d-_\s]+)*" />
   <action type="Rewrite" url="page?isCategory=true&amp;categories={R:1}&amp;other={R:2}&amp;all={R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

but it doesn't give me all the path it just gives me this
**

> isCategory=true&categories=xxx&other=/zzz&all=content/category/xxx/yyy/zzz

**
for this input

> https://localhost:44354/content/category/xxx/yyy/zzz

anybody knows why other is /zzz I expect it to be /xxx/yyy/zzz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your rule is the regular expression inside the  element. There are multiple segments (xxx, yyy, zzz) in the example URL, if you want to capture multiple segments, you can modify the regex pattern as follows:

```
<match url="^content/category(/([a-zA-Z\d-_\s]+)((/[a-zA-Z\d-_\s]+)*))" />
```

For this input:

> https://localhost:44354/content/category/xxx/yyy/zzz

You will get the following capture groups:

```
{R:0}   content/category/xxx/yyy/zzz
{R:1}   /xxx/yyy/zzz
{R:2}   xxx
{R:3}   /yyy/zzz
{R:4}   /zzz
```

If you want to get `categories=xxx` and `other=/xxx/yyy/zzz`
you can modify the rewrite URL like this:

```
<action type="Rewrite" url="page?isCategory=true&amp;categories={R:2}&amp;other={R:1}&amp;all={R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
```

It will give you all the path you want:

> isCategory=true&categories=xxx&other=/xxx/yyy/zzz&all=content/category/xxx/yyy/zzz

Comment: I tried your pattern but seems not working, I changed it to 
<match url="^content/category/(([a-zA-Z\d-_\s]+)((/[a-zA-Z\d-_\s]+)*))" /> and now it's working!
Thanks a lot, I didn't know references could be nested like this very helpful answer.